# Column operations and conditions in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a framework which works with columns as main objects:

```
template <typename T>
class Column : private std::vector<T>
{
public:
  typedef typename std::vector<T> Container;
  // using vector's methods
  using Container::...
};
```

I have add arithmetic operations:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator+(const Column<T1>& c1, const Column<T2>& c2) -> Column<decltype(c1[0] + c2[0])>;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator+(const Column<T1>& c1, T2 scalar) -> Column<decltype(c1[0] + scalar)>;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator+(T1 scalar, const Column<T2>& c2) -> Column<decltype(scalar + c2[0])>;
// and others like -, /, abs, sin, <, <=, >, &&, ...
```

No I can use Column in all kind of mathematical operations. Yet I also would like to do column conditional operations (then statement executes only for rows with condition true):

```
Column<bool> condition; // fill with {false, true, true, false}
Column<double> a; // fill with {0, 1, 2, 3}
Column<double> b;
IF (condition)
([&a, &b]()
{
  b = a + 1; // desired b column: {0, 2, 3, 3}
})
```

Is it possible to do something like that (to hide indices inside some conditional functor IF)?

Comment: I would probably use only arithmetic operators and stick to a matlab-like syntax `b = a + 1*condition`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specialize your `Column<bool>` version by adding a member function taking a lambda as parameter. The function would call it for every `true` index.
Something like this (written on the fly) :

```
template<typename F>
void ifTrue(F& lambda) {
    for (auto it : vector) {
        if (value == true) {
            lambda();
        }
    }
}
```